# Sum sets in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

I can't seem to find a method to solve the following problem:
I have a range of strings in `A1:A`, and some relevant numbers in `B1:B`. The same goes for `C1:C` and `D1:D`. **Neither** column A or column C is ordered or unique. What I would like to achive, is the in range `E1:E` I have a UNION of `A1:A` and `C1:C` with unique values only (ordering does not matter), and in column `F1:F` I have the values summed for the given strings.

[image: Sample]

If I did have the function to give me `E1:E` I would be able to manage the sums with the `SUMIF` function.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get **unique values** from `Column A` and `Column C` combined, enter the following formula in `Cell E2`

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$5, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($E$1:E1, $A$2:$A$5), 0)), INDEX($C$2:$C$6, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($E$1:E1, $C$2:$C$6), 0))), "")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then to get **sum** of corresponding values across `Column B` and `Column D`, use any of the below two formulas

`=SUMIF($A$2:$A$5,E2,$B$2:$B$5)+SUMIF($C$2:$C$6,E2,$D$2:$D$6)`

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5=E2)*$B$2:$B$5)+SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$6=E2)*$D$2:$D$6)`

Drag/Copy down formulas as required. See image for reference

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick help, working as charm.